# Saving the current running aspx page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an aspx page with a table that runs at server. I wrote a code to insert a row in the table, as the code bellow shows. I want to save the now updated aspx page (i.e overwriting the current if possible) so that the next time I visit the page, all information shows. I don't want to use a database to store this information because this is only temporary and my hosting package does not support a database. Please help.

Below is my code:

```
 Dim trow As New HtmlTableRow
    Dim tcell As New HtmlTableCell

    tcell.InnerText = "Code: " & TextBox1.Text & ".   Weight: " & TextBox2.Text & ". Date: " & Now
    trow.Cells.Add(tcell)

    trow.Cells.Add(tcell)

    Table.Rows.Add(trow)
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    'Save the aspx page
    Me.SaveControlState()
    Me.SaveViewState()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the data in cookies. Try this.

```
Writing a cookie.

HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

// Set the cookie value.
myCookie.Value = now.ToString();
// Set the cookie expiration date.
myCookie.Expires = now.AddYears(50); // For a cookie to effectively never expire

// Add the cookie.
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);

Response.Write("<p> The cookie has been written.");
```

Reading a cookie

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
myCookie = Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"];

// Read the cookie information and display it.
if (myCookie != null)
    Response.Write("<p>"+ myCookie.Name + "<p>"+ myCookie.Value);
else
    Response.Write("not found");
```

Comment: It is a good Idea but I really don't know how to use it. I am still a learner. This is how I used your code:
            Dim myCookie As New HttpCookie("MyTestCookie")
            myCookie = Request.Cookies("MyTestCookie")

            ' Read the cookie information and display it.
            If myCookie IsNot Nothing Then
                Response.Write(("<p>" + myCookie.Name & "<p>") + myCookie.Value)
            Else
                Response.Write("not found")
            End If
        Else
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
        End If

Answer (score 0):

Use session:

to access a value:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session(“MyVariable”).ToString()
```

to set a value:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session(“MyVariable”) = “NewValue”
```

Comment: The OP wants the data to persist for the next visit so a Session variable will not work